# mysql_fetch_array how to display a single value of a column

Tags: php

I have the query fetching 8 rows, I want to be able access the result by single column not the whole row. For example I want to display the Deviceid from row number 7. i can display all of the values of the column but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get just one value. I'm new to PHP so bear with me and thank you for any help.
This the code:

```
 <?php
 $con = mysql_connect("uimcswpro", "testmysql", "test123") or die('Could not connect to server');
 mysql_select_db("storage", $con) or die('Sorry, could not connect to the database');

 $query = "Select distinct a.Deviceid as Deviceid, c.Time as Time, b.devicehostname as devicehostname, ElementName, PoolID,
 TotalManagedSpace, RemainingManagedSpace,
 TotalDiskCapacity, HotspareCapacity, UnassignedStorageCapacity,
 AssignedStorageCapacity 
 from tt_cim_storage_pool a, devices b, ent_san_storage_current c
 where a.Deviceid = b.Deviceid
 and (type = 'Unified Pool' or type = 'RAID Group' or type is NULL)
 and c.time = (select max(c.Time) from tt_cim_storage_pool where deviceid=
 (select deviceid from devices where devicehostname='UIH_8100_L14' and retire=0))
 and devicehostname='UIH_8100_L14';";

 $result = mysql_query($query,$con);
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
 echo "$num_rows Rows\n";
 echo "<br/>";

 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo $row[0]. " - ".$row[1]. " - ".$row['devicehostname']. " - ".$row['ElementName'].   " - ".$row['PoolID']
 . " - ".$row['TotalDiskCapacity'];
 echo "<br/>";
 }

 mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: Your query can return more than one row. You'll either need to be more specific in your SQL by adding "AND a.Deviceid = n" or loop through the rows of the result array for the Deviceid you want.

Comment: the query is just for one deviceid. Every deviceid returns several rows because every device has several arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select desired row via sql using LIMIT keyword, or simple checking number of current row:

```
$rowNo = 0;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 $rowNo++;
 if ($rowNo == 7) {
   echo $row[0]. " - ".$row[1]. " - ".$row['devicehostname']. " - ".$row['ElementName'].   " - ".$row['PoolID']
 . " - ".$row['TotalDiskCapacity'];
   echo "<br/>";
 }
}
```

You should also consider using modern database interface like mysqli

Comment: Thank you @ziollek. This is the display I got:3 -            1393224682318 - UIH_8100_L14 - Ungrouped Disks - Ungrouped Disks - 9749982609408. What I'm trying to do is pass just one value of this row into a variable, for example 'UIH_8100_L14'. Any ideas how to do that? Thank you for the quick reply again :).